# How to shard a collection for ranged queries on a monotnic key?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with a field called height. The height monotonically increases i.e. each new document effectively has a height of previous document's height +1.

I want to shard this collection as I know this collection will grow quite large. The type of queries I would run on this collection are basically to support pagination and they will all use the height as the page token.

Example of a query I would run:

```
db.collection1.find({ 
    height: { $lt: 1000) 
    })
    .sort({ height: -1 })
    .limit(100)
```

**Question: Is ranged sharding i.e. using height as the shard key the best strategy for these queries?**

My thinking so far:

If I use [hashed sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/hashed-sharding/), documents with heights that are close together will get spread out across different shards. So this is not optimum strategy for my queries.

If I use [ranged sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/ranged-sharding/), all writes will consistently end up on one shard since the height always increases. But reads for historic data should still be able to take advantage of the shards. I may have to occasionally add new shards to continue spreading the new data.

[Zoned sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-shard-zone/)sounds like could also work, but seems more complex than ranged sharding.